# Can one drop multiple views at once in Impala

Tags: sql, impala

I have a database with three views. I am trying to execute a command to drop all three at once.

The [Impala Guide](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/impala_drop_view.html) shows it is possible to drop one view at a time using

`DROP VIEW IF EXISTS mydb.view_name`

But it does not suggest a method for dropping more than one view, the the same time [this page](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/impala_views.html#views) from the Guide does not suggest this would be a restriction .

If I were using SQL server (and other versions of SQL), I could follow the method shown in [this tutorial](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-views/sql-server-drop-view/), separating the views by a `,`.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS 
                   mydb.view_v1,
                   mydb.view_v2,
                   mydb.view_v3;
```

I would expect this to drop the three views from the database.

However when I try this in Impala I get the below error:

```
AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 2:undefined: ...exists mydb.view_v1, mydb.view_v2, mydb... ^ Encountered: COMMA Expected: ADD, ALTER, AS, CACHED, CHANGE, COMMENT, DROP, FROM, LIKE, LOCATION, PARTITION, PARTITIONED, PRIMARY, PURGE, RECOVER, RENAME, REPLACE, ROW, SELECT, SET, SORT, STORED, STRAIGHT_JOIN, TBLPROPERTIES, TO, UNCACHED, VALUES, WITH CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
```

and all views remain.

Comment: I can't readily think of any database that supports dropping multiple views -- or multiple anything -- in a single statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the error indicates that in Impala terms your statement is not syntactically correct (and not supported).

The only way I can think of to simulate something similar to what you need is to place all views into a separate database, and then run a [`DROP DATABASE ... CASCADE`](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_drop_database.html). I expect this operation to behave atomically, i.e either succeed of fail as a single unit.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it was my suspicion that it wasn't supported. I've gone with a more basic and executed the three drop statements in a row. I think the `DROP ... CASCADE` would require me to drop the underlying table, which is something I cannot do.

Comment: I don't think `DROP DATABASE db_with_views CASCADE` will do anything to the tables if tables are in a different database `db_with_tables`.